# Creating a ArrayList from a IObservableList - Is it possible

Tags: java

I was creating a new ArrayList from a ArrayList in a different class.

```
  ArrayList<AplotDataModel.AplotDatasetData> tableData = AplotDataModel.getInstance().getArrayData();
```

I have since changed the arraylist in the other class to a IOservableList.
So I hoped it would be as simple as changing to the method to get the ObservableList instead of the ArrayList

```
 ArrayList<AplotDataModel.AplotDatasetData> tableData = AplotDataModel.getInstance().getObservableList();
```

I get the following error:

Type mismatch: cannot convert from IObservableList to ArrayList

***EDIT***
AplotDatasetData is a subclass of AplotDataModel.

```
 public class AplotDatasetData {

  TCComponentItemRevision rev;
  TCComponentDataset   componentdataset;
  String prlValue;
  String datasetName;
  String markUp = "No";

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //                           Constructor                                //
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public AplotDatasetData(TCComponentItemRevision tcRevision, TCComponentDataset selectedDataset) {
     rev = tcRevision;
     componentdataset = selectedDataset;

  }// end Constructor

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //                            getDataset()                               //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public TCComponent getDataset() {
     return componentdataset;
  }// end getDataset()

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //                               getRev()                                //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public TCComponent getRev() {
     return rev;
  }// end getRev()

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //                             getPRLValue()                             //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public String getPRLValue() {
     try {
        prlValue = rev.getRelatedComponent("IMAN_master_form_rev").getStringProperty("PRL");
     }
     catch (TCException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return prlValue;
  }// end getPRLValue()

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //                           getDatasetName()                            //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public String getDatasetName() {
     try {
        datasetName = componentdataset.getStringProperty("object_string");
     }
     catch (TCException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return datasetName;
  }// end getDatasetName()

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //                          getECMarkupValue()                           //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public String getMarkupValue() {
     return markUp;
  }// end getECMarkupValue()

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //                          setECMarkupValue()                           //
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public void setMarkupValue(String markupValue) {
     markUp = markupValue;

  }// end getECMarkupValue()
```

That is my base Data Model.  The user selects data that sends 
TCComponentItemRevision rev;
TCComponentDataset   componentdataset;

to the ObservableList, then I use AplotDatasetData to get more information from rev, componentdataset to populate my table.

So the user clicks a button on the GUI that opens a new gui dialog.  The new Gui also has a table with a couple of new columns - I am just trying to get the ObservableList that was populated by the users in the first GUI and use it to build a new arraylist.

Can a ObservableList not extend a class like AplotDatasetData?

Comment: does `IOservableList` extends `ArrayList`? More code could help.

Comment: Try `IObservableList tableData = ...`

Comment: Why do you think an IObservableList could be assigned to a variable of type ArrayList? Unless IObservableList extends ArrayList, that would be like assigning a banana to a variable of type Car.

Comment: why put this in an `ArrayList`?  Just put this in a `List`.

Comment: Your code should really be shown as an example of how NOT to use comments :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new ArrayList from a Collection. Since `org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.list.IObservableList` is a Collection,

```
ArrayList<AplotDataModel.AplotDatasetData> tableData = new ArrayList<AplotDataModel.AplotDatasetData>(AplotDataModel.getInstance().getObservableList());
```

should work.

If you don't need an ArrayList, you can also just assign the IObservableList to a List:

```
List<AplotDataModel.AplotDatasetData> tableData = AplotDataModel.getInstance().getObservableList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the generic in the tableData ArrayList to support IObservable:

```
ArrayList<IObservable> tableData = AplotDataModel.getInstance().getObservableList();
```

Basically, you initially said I have a basket full of apples. Put that pile of apples over there into my apple basket.

Then, you went and changed the pile from apples to oranges. Now, you're saying put that pile of oranges into my apple basket. You're thinking that you can put oranges into it because it's a basket - but you can't. It's an apple basket. Change it to an orange basket.

**EDIT**

I misread the question. You need IObservableList to extend ArrayList if you want it to work.

Comment: The list itself is an IObservalbeList. It's not the generic type of the list which causes problem.

Comment: I guess `IObservableList` is not a user class.

Comment: Then a one liner isn't going to be possible. He'll have to manually iterate through the list and pass each value in.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I don't know what AplotDataModel is, but you can make use of `<?extends ?>`, like:

```
Class c = AplotDataModel.getInstance().getClass();
ArrayList<?extends c ?> tableData = AplotDataModel.getInstance().getObservableList();
```

or

```
ArrayList<?extends IObservalbeList ?> tableData = AplotDataModel.getInstance().getObservableList();
```

Comment: Read the question. The generic type of the list is not the problem. The OP takes an instance of IObservableList, and tries to assign it to ArrayList. And your code is not valid Java code.

Comment: then put the result in `List` variable